# Is it possible to create own pointer qualification in C++03/11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to append extra user-defined qualifications to pointer like

```
mymem const void *A;     // Compiled
mymem const void *B = A; // Compiler
const void *C = A;       // Not compiled
```

C++ allow to have cv-qualificaions and real compiler allow some extension on it (like restrict).
But is it possible to create own qualifers and distinguish between them?

Via some C++ class/object mechanism or via C preprocessor.

Comment: Nope, there's no such mechanism in any revision of C++.

Comment: You can write a class that has an `operator->` and do whatever you like with it. Syntactically it will act like a pointer.

Comment: What would they do? How would you define their properties?

Comment: @Pete mmm, how can I write this class? Can you give me simple example? (I want to use standart C++/C syntax for pointer qualifications)

Comment: @Galik, in C++ there are already several qualifications (cv). I can imagine several possible use cases why i need extra - have aligned pointers (8,16,32,64). And not allow to mix pointers of different alignments....Or maybe pointer is not a pointer to data in adress in user space, but some specific device adress which can not be dereferenced.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for pointing into it. If so how to emulate it.

Comment: @bruziuz I can understand having a use for extra qualifiers. But I was curious as to how you would tell the compiler what effect the new qualifiers would have? How do you define their function?

Comment: Actually I would like to perform function/template overloading based on this qualifications.. I hope to not touch compiler at all and don't communicate with them.

Comment: [This sounds like an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem are you trying to solve. No, not about adding qualifiers to pointers, but the real problem for which you believe the solution is to create a custom pointer qualifier. Based on your last comment, that sounds to be something that can be handled using smart overloading and SFINAE. For example, standard algorithms like `std::distance` can select different overloads based on whether the iterators are random access or not. No custom qualifiers are necessary.

Comment: My real problem - is append user defined qualifiers and disallow pointers conversion with different qualifiers and define function overloading based on this qualifiers....Looks that append user-defined class can be a solution for c++ code...But I'm open for futher discussions

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326865